# CSS Positioning inconsistent across browsers

Tags: css, positioning

I'm running into some positioning inconsistencies between browsers. I'm trying to position a submit button so that it hovers over the lower corner of the textarea.

In Chrome, Safari, and other browsers this works just like it should:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

However, in Firefox, I get this:

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

Is there a different method for positioning that element, or have I left something out of my CSS?

Here is the link to the HTMl and the CSS: http://www.tylonius.com/clients/X10/GalleryDisplay.html

Comment: CSS and HTML code please

Comment: Are you setting the font size anywhere? Try setting "html {font-size:1em;}" so the font size on the whole page is normalized. It might ned to be set to 100% or an absolute value like 16px. I haven't done this in a little while and am not certain.

Comment: Needs more information like the sizing of the parent containers as they compare in both Chrome and Firefox to know where the math is off.

Comment: Are you using any kind of css reset?  http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Yes, there is a reset in place. The page is actually a comp for a custom WordPress template, so all of the standard WP elements are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dropped that screenshot into photoshop and measured the bottom padding of the containing element. In the top image it's `11px` high. In the bottom image it is `13px`. I'm guessing that's your problem, but without seeing your code it's impossible to say for sure. Try looking at the CSS of the surrounding elements. I don't think the `<input>` elements are your problem.

**EDIT**

Now that I can see your code I'm certain this answer is correct. The problem is the length of the surrounding box. What you need to do is take the styling from `#gallery-commentform` and apply it to a div containing the form. then absolutely position the `textarea` adn the `submit` relative to the bottom left hand corner. that way no matter how browsers render the height/padding/yaddayadda it will always be the same distance from the bottom of the form.

Comment: it's a great looking form, btw

Answer (score 1):

**Position that submit button absolutely.**

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Make sure it's parent element's position is set to `relative`.

Comment: Nope. Absolute positioning will not work with the collapsible comment input. If it were that simple, I wouldn't have bothered anyone. :-)

Comment: @TyMorton Yup. Yes it is; throw up the HTML/CSS in a fiddle and I will prove it.

Comment: I stand corrected! I had tried that before, but the parent element wasn't the DIV, it was the form. When I set that to relative and tried it, it worked perfectly!

Comment: The window in the back is Firefox. You can see that it is still a couple of pixels off.

Comment: It's like a pixel off in Firefox.

Comment: I turned out to be the result of the inconsistent way in which browsers handle form elements. The combined suggestions pulled it all together as best as could be expected. It's still off by like a half pixel, but much closer than it was. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: @TyMorton Which is why I like to make everything as block level with a defined width and height as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with a lot of issues like this recently, the first thing I would do is check padding, margin, and border.  I'd bet that Firefox sets some default properties differently than the other browsers, and you need to override that.  The 'computed styles' tab in inspector should be enough to figure out if that's the case.